# Apache directory studio NPE when viewing certificates

Tags: apache, nullpointerexception, reset, apache-directory

After playing for a while with Apache Directory Studio, I have a number of certificates in the Certificate Validation list:

Click: Windows > Preferences ... then Expand: Apache Directory Studio > Connections > Certificate Validation ... The list displays under "Permanent Trusted" to the right.

I'm trying to delete those certificates, but whenever you click any of them a NPE exception dialog is shown and cannot select or click Remove button.

Is there some way to reset/clear all application data in Apache Directory Studio to start from scratch? Without having to uninstall/reinstall everything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this is a bug reported here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DIRSTUDIO-1095

And this seems to be fixed in next release.

Anyway, if you are using it on Mac OS X, the application settings are at `~/.ApacheDirectoryStudio`. On other platforms, this should be located in your home directory.

Here is the official document;
http://directory.apache.org/studio/faqs.html#location-of-apache-directory-studio-settings